# Paris Visite Pass and CDG Airport transfer to main city center

Tags: airport-transfer, cdg

I would like to know whether the Paris Visite Pass covers the transfer from CDG Airport transfer to city center hotel through RER B, if purchased at CDG Airport?

Comment: Note that you can also use a Mobilis ticket covering zones 1-5.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the official [website](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/paris-visite-travel-pass)

> Valid for 1, 2, 3 or 5 consecutive days, the pass allows you to travel anywhere in Paris (zones 1 to 3) or in Paris and the Île-de-France region (all zones, **including airport connections**, Orlyval, Disneyland Paris and Château de Versailles).

So, yes, you can take the RER-B from the airport to Paris.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to buy the version that covers zones 1-5.